# What sites offer modern Rails hosting

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, list, hosting, shared

Is there a list anywhere of shared hosting sites that support the newest ruby   Rails versions. The only one of the famous ones I can find is apparently DreamHost, other than that most seem to have ancient versions. I'm not asking which is better, I'm just asking for an objective quality, i.e. version numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at my answer here: [Best hosting for Ruby on Rails (as of 2012)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11436930/best-hosting-for-ruby-on-rails-as-of-2012/11437013#11437013)

This is a pretty up-to-date list, the other answers should be helpful as well.